# How to disable UITabBarItem in a button click?

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.2

I am developing an iOS application with UITabBarController. I want to set the user interaction of the first tabbaritem will be NO in the second child viewController(One button action), ie the view flow is:

firstTabbarItem -> firstChildView ->secondChildView ->buttonClick(set firstTabbarItem userInteraction is NO).

How can implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the tab bar item directly:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem.enabled = NO;
```

Just call that in your button handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at

[UITabbarControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), you can have your AppDelegate to implement that protocol, and respondo no to TabbarController:shouldSelectViewController